# Search results signature is set to null in arabic language

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1 and SXA 1.8.1.
My site have two languages: english and arabic.

I've recently run into a problem which is the following:
All the search results components stopped returning any data in the arabic language.

After checking the search results API request i found that the Signature in the arabic language is set to null.

```
{
"TotalTime": 0,
"CountTime": 0,
"QueryTime": 0,
"Signature": null,
"Index": null,
"Count": 0,
"Results": []
}
```

Also after checking the logs files i found the below error repeated.

```
    ERROR Item must have more than 1 version in the default language (ar-AE)
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Item must have more than 1 version in the default language (ar-AE)
Source: Sitecore.ContentSearch
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.EnsureFallbackVersion(Item rootItem)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Item rootItem, TemplateID templateId)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Item rootItem, String templateId)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.QueryBuilder.CreateQuery[T](IProviderSearchContext context, IEnumerable`1 searchStringModel, Item startLocationItem, IEnumerable`1 additionalContexts)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.QueryBuilder.CreateQuery[T](IProviderSearchContext context, IEnumerable`1 searchStringModel)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService.GetQuery(SearchQueryModel searchQueryModel, String& indexName)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetResults(QueryModel model)
```

I'm not really sure what might be the root cause of this issue and if the above error is related or not?

Comment: Do you need a check somewhere to ensure that the queried items have Arabic versions?